# How to change Class From jquery but remove that class from another object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have problem. i don't no how to fix that problem

HTML Code:

```
<div class="image">
 <a href="#">
       <img src="images/image1.jpg" id="mainimg-1">
  </a>
</div>

      <div class="otherthumbnailcontainer">
        <div class="thumbnailimages" id="thumbnailcont-1">
            <img src="images/image1.jpg" id="thumbnail-1" onMouseOver="changeimage('images/image1.jpg','mainimg-1','thumbnail-1','thumbnailcont-1');" class="thumbsmallimg selectedthumb">

            <img src="images/image2.jpg" id="thumbnail-2" onMouseOver="changeimage('images/image2.jpg','mainimg-1','thumbnail-2','thumbnailcont-1');" class="thumbsmallimg">

            <img src="images/image3.jpg" id="thumbnail-3" onMouseOver="changeimage('images/image3.jpg','mainimg-1','thumbnail-3','thumbnailcont-1');" class="thumbsmallimg">

            <img src="images/image4.jpg" id="thumbnail-4" onMouseOver="changeimage('images/image4.jpg','mainimg-1','thumbnail-4','thumbnailcont-1');" class="thumbsmallimg">  

            <img src="images/image5.jpg" id="thumbnail-5" onMouseOver="changeimage('images/image5.jpg','mainimg-1','thumbnail-5','thumbnailcont-1');" class="thumbsmallimg">  
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is code:

```
function changeimage(thumburl,mainimgid,thumbnailimg,thumbmaindiv)
{
     $('#'+mainimgid).attr("src", thumburl);
    // $('#'+thumbnailimg).add("thumbsmallimg selectedthumb");
     $('#'+thumbnailimg).removeClass("selectedthumb").addClass('thumbsmallimg');
     // $('#'+thumbnailimg).toggleClass("selectedthumb");
}
```

Now what i would like to do on the website page is completely load the first image with these two class "thumbsmallimg selectedthumb" but when mouse goes over on another image the class "selectedthumb" will switch from one image to another.

**EDIT:**
http://jsfiddle.net/nZMpW/ Check this link. its like a product image gallery when you hover mouse on down image its come in big image. but first down image is selected if you move on another image its come in big image but is not select. css this ":hover" option only work when you mouse on that image but i don't want to do this

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Do you want to use a CSS class like: `.selectedthumb{backgound:url(someURL.png)}` or something? Make sure you make the entire thing as one image, to avoid flashing. Then you can do something like `.selectedthumb:hover{background-position:0 -20px};`.

Comment: i want to switch this class "selectedthumb" to another images when mouse is hovered

Comment: Thanks for your advice! but when you again remove mouse from that image  that image come old style. i don't want to do this when mouse come on image this should br select like active @PHPglue

Comment: jsfiddle.net/nZMpW check this like now i think you understand what i want? sorry for that my English is not good that why im not explain clearly @PHPglue

Comment: Just use `$('#id').mouseenter(function(){$(this).css('backgroundPosition', '0 -20px')});`. Change `this` if not referring to `$('#id')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove all you onmouseover events and use this jquery code in the $(document).ready() section

```
 $(".thumbsmallimg").mouseover(function() {
     $("#mainimg-1").attr("src", this.src);
     $(".selectedthumb").removeClass("selectedthumb");
     $(this).addClass("selectedthumb");    
 });
```

and, if you want it to work with several sets of thumbnails/bigImages, you can use data() attributes:

```
  <img src="http://www.yoono.com/static/yoono_com_v8/img/iphone_yoono.png" id="thumbnail-1"  class="thumbsmallimg selectedthumb" data-big-image="mainimg-1">
  <img src="http://www1.pcmag.com/media/images/302835-apple-iphone-5-sprint.jpg" id="thumbnail-2"  class="thumbsmallimg" data-big-image="mainimg-1">
 .....
```

and in jqQuery:

```
$(".thumbsmallimg").mouseover(function() {
    $("#" + $(this).data("big-image")).attr("src", this.src);
    $(".selectedthumb").removeClass("selectedthumb");
    $(this).addClass("selectedthumb");    
});
```

here is your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nZMpW/4/) updated again

Answer (score 1):

instead having selectedthumb, in your css put those styles inside  .thumbsmallimg:hover{

```
.thumbsmallimg:hover{
  /* the styles that wrere in class .selectedthumb */
}
```

Comment: +1. This should be the preferable way to give styling on hover. Use JS only when CSS does not solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! What you said is not the way i want to do. I want to when mouse come on thumbnail image the come to big image on down this thumbnail should be selected

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nZMpW/ check this like now i think you understand what i want? sorry for that my English is not good that why im not explain clearly

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nZMpW/1/ just like i said. changing .selectedthumb by .thumbsmallimg:hover in css file